# Concurrently write pandas DataFrame to xlsx

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, save

I have one `DataFrame` which needs to be segmented and written to different excel files based on a specific column...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(28).reshape((7, 4)))

df['group'] = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e']


    0   1   2   3   group
0   0   1   2   3   a
1   4   5   6   7   a
2   8   9   10  11  c
3   12  13  14  15  c
4   16  17  18  19  d
5   20  21  22  23  d
6   24  25  26  27  e
```

based on the column `group` I need to split and write to xlsx files... I currently use

```
for group in list(df['group'].unique()):
    group_df = df[df['group'] == group]
    group_df.to_excel(some_path)
```

Is there a way I could do this concurrently, rather than with a for loop??

Comment: I'm not sure that doing it in parallel will be faster, unless you are writing to SSD disk or to a proper storage system or distributed file system...

Comment: Not necessarily going to speed up using concurrency but the operation could be sped up by using the `.groupby()` method... `for name, group in df.groupby('group'):`

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. You would still need a for loop to break out into the individual threads.

That being said, you won't see any performance gains from using concurrency here. You have no external blocking APIs, and your operation is certainly IO limited as opposed to CPU.